# How to make apache read htaccess

Tags: apache-httpd, nas

my document root is /data
i've added

```
<Directory /data>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to my default conf below /Virtualhost
but the apache still wont read no htaccess

What am i missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there some other change to be made in order for the apache to go to /data?

Comment: Hello BlackArch.py, what are you trying to accomplish? Why are you using htaccess file? see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: Dumb question maybe, but is your htacces with a dot? `.htaccess`